# react-hook-form error: transformToNestObject is not a function

Tags: reactjs, yup, react-hook-form

I want to use Material-UI radio buttons, after the `react-hook-form` update the validation throws the following error:

```
transformToNestObject is not a function
```

Is the `Controller` wrapper not correct?

[Sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-validationschema-v7-ts-forked-cpnjo?file=/src/index.tsx)

```
  <Controller
    render={({ field, fieldState }) => (
      <RadioGroup {...field} aria-label="option">
        <FormControlLabel
          value="A"
          control={<Radio size="small" color="primary" />}
          label="A"
        />
        <FormControlLabel
          value="B"
          control={<Radio size="small" color="primary" />}
          label="B"
        />
      </RadioGroup>
    )}
    name="option"
    control={control}
  />
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try upgrading `@hookform/resolvers` package to the latest version. [Source](https://github.com/react-hook-form/resolvers/pull/125/files#r568512333).